# 301 URL redirect using GET variables

Tags: http, .htaccess, redirect, apache

We have a URL that needs to be redirected based on the values of two URL variables. The http request is as follows: **`http://img.ourserver.com/junk/imgfolder?var1=size&var2=imgname`**. This URL should redirect to the following **`http://img.ourserver.com/imgfolder/size/imgname.png`**

We can do this either in an .htaccess file or the Apache conf file.

Thanks!

Comment: So, what have you tried?  You can do this using `RewriteRule` in your Apache configuration in combination with `RewriteCond`; there have been a number of questions here on SO in the past month or so that touch on this topic.

Comment: Our main problem is that this is effectively the opposite of a normal rewrite since our users will be providing the URL with vars, and we need to redirect to a clean directory structure. I haven't had much luck finding Q's that relate to this—especially with multiple variables on SA.

Comment: Well, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244881/rewrite-query-string), for example, shows how to match arbitrary chunks of text in the query string and then substitute them into the target of a `RewriteRule`.  This example only extracts a single chunk of text from the query string, but you can obviously generalize the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)var1=([^&]+)&var2=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/(imgfolder)/?$ $1/%1/%2.png? [L,R,NC]
```