# Htaccess redirect URL not working properly. Redirection only working on page refresh or when I open it in new tab

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

When I enter URL, htaccess redirect it to 404 page. But when I refresh that page, it started working. I don't know why this is happening. Please suggest me how  do I fix that problem.

URL :

```
http://localhost/mydomain/private_memorial&user_id=12&page_id=5
```

htaccess:

```
RewriteRule

private_memorial&user_id=([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)&page_id=([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$

index.php?link1=private_memorial&user_id=$1&page_id=$2 [NC,QSA]
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please add your htaccess code. without code we can't identify the problem and can't provide the solution. clearly define the problem, error message with htaccess code

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: brother, please add htaccess code here.

Comment: My URL is : http://localhost/mydomain/private_memorial&user_id=12&page_id=5    and My htaccess code is :  RewriteRule private_memorial&user_id=([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)&page_id=([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?link1=private_memorial&user_id=$1&page_id=$2 [NC,QSA]

Comment: add above code into your question

Comment: is that ALL of the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: No, there are lot of codes in htaccess file

Comment: `mod_rewrite` does not operate on query strings. You can add a [query string condition](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString) though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rewrite Query String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244881/rewrite-query-string)