# Rewrite home page url and remove question mark and add slashes in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I found a lot of solutions online but all of them require a page, and i am trying to do it on the main page like

[www.domain.com?address=germany](http://www.domain.com?address=germany)

to

[www.domain.com/germany](http://www.domain.com/germany)

Comment: Is your "main page" a true file like `index.php` or is it a virtual file handled by a routing system? Can you post what you've tried. Have you see this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/1244948/231316

Comment: My Main page is the index.php, but i don't want it like www.domain.com/index/germany

Comment: Then the above should be able to help you

Comment: Once again, please post what you have tried and what the results where.

Answer (score 1):

You should have your htaccess rule like following. Rules which are posted by OP in OP's answer doesn't look correct to me. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /index.php?address=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just edit the .htaccess and write this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?address=$1 [L]
```

Comment: IMHO, this will give an error, not sure if you have checked this rule, have a look to my answer how it should be, thank you